# Is there a way to query for element with multiple classes in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I query for an element that have two classes at the same time?

For example:

```
<div><span class="major minor">Test</span></div>
```

I want to style all the spans that have "major" and "minor" classes at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
span.major.minor { color: red; }
```

Note you have to be careful with this with Internet Explorer 6 - it will only read the last class of the selector. For example, it will incorrectly apply the rule above to the following:

```
<span class="minor">Test</span>
```

Comment: span.major.minor != span.minor.major

Comment: @in.spite, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

Use the class qualifier twice, eg.:

```
.major.minor { ... }
```

**But**. It doesn't work in IE6 (or in IE7 either when in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)). When you specify multiple class selectors on the same element, IE only pays attention to the last one. So the above selector would match any element with `class="minor"`.

Workarounds include duplicating multiple classes as a single class:

```
.major-minor { ... }
<span class="major minor major-minor">...</span>
```

Or, if spare elements are available to make it clean, containment:

```
.major .minor { ... }
<span class="major"><span class="minor">...</span></span>
```