# How would I write css to access the following class "total total_plus hidden_elem" or "total total_plus"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How would I write css to access the following class "total total_plus hidden_elem" or "total total_plus"?

I have class="total total_plus" and class="total total_plus_elem" and I need to access them via css. What would be the proper way to access them?

```
.total total_plus
{
     display:none;
}
```

is not working for me.

Here is the context of what I am trying to access:

```
<div class="bigbox">
   <div class="full_widget">
       <div class="connections">
          <span class="total total_plus"></span>
          <span class="total hidden_elem"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to query for element with multiple classes in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721049/is-there-a-way-to-query-for-element-with-multiple-classes-in-css)

Comment: This is not a dupe. I've added further information to assist.

Comment: How is it *not* a dupe? Did the answers there and the one below not help?

Comment: Please close your tags in your HTML. It's not 100% clear whether your first span is containing the second.

Comment: Hmm how do the duplicate's answers not help?

Comment: @Bolt: I see how you could think that would help - and it did just a little. I am just stumped trying to access them in the context. Am I overthinking this? I saw MadMarty said .total would be adequate but I have tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like a specificity issue. You can use one of the parent elements with `.total`, or you can just use `.total.total_plus, .total.hidden_elem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, all classes in CSS must be written directly after each another – with no white space.

```
.total.total_plus
```

and

```
.total.hidden_elem
```

Comment: If accessing both elements in the same rule, put them together with a comma in between.

Comment: I think OP's meaning of "or" is the same as saying "both". As in `p, li {}` selects `p` "or" `li` (so it selects both). Maybe I'm mistaken, but the post does little to clarify if I am. In this exact case, just `.total` is sufficient, but of course it's probably crucial to be more specific, so this is the correct answer.